# Resolve promise in $stateProvider then use results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I want to resolve a promise in a stateprovider since I have to use the results of the promise in another promise.

I am not so sure how to do that. I did something like this

```
 app
    .config(['$stateProvider','GeolocationService',
      function($stateProvider,geolocation){
        $stateProvider.state('sendCoords',{
          resolve: {
            long: function (geolocation) {
              geolocation().then(function (position) {
                return position.coords.longitude;
              }, function (reason) {
                return false;
              })
            },
            lat: function (geolocation) {
              geolocation().then(function (position) {
                return position.coords.longitude;
              }, function (reason) {
                return false;
              })
            }
          },
          controller: 'appCtrl'
        })

      }
    ]);
```

Is this even correct? I want the geolocation resolved and then use the 'lat' and 'long' variables in my controller.

```
app.controller('appCtrl',['$scope','serviceTest',function($scope,serviceTest,lat,long){
       $scope.optionsToChoose = [];
        serviceTest.options(long,lat).then(
          function (option) {
            $scope.optionsToChoose = option;
          },
          function(error){
          }
        );
}]
```

However, injecting lat and long like this, they are not defined. I am sure I make some bad mistake here, but I do not really get it. Hope you can help me.

EDIT: Here is the Geolocation Service Code

```
app.factory("GeolocationService", ['$q', '$window', '$rootScope',
  function ($q, $window, $rootScope) {
    return function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer();

      if (!$window.navigator) {
        $rootScope.$apply(function() {
          deferred.reject(new Error("Geolocation is not supported"));
        });
      } else {
        $window.navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            deferred.resolve(position);
          });
        }, function (error) {
          $rootScope.$apply(function() {
            deferred.reject(error);
          });
        });
      }

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  }]);
```

Comment: For one thing, you have to `return` the promise to have it be resolved, i.e. `return geolocation().then....`. But you're saying that you need to "resolve geolocation". Here you inject it. Is `geolocation` an injectable service or is this something you also need to resolve?

Comment: also be simpler to resolve them as one object. Show the `geolocation` service code

Comment: There are two promises in play here. First the geolocation giving me the long and lat. I want to  use those two to inject in another promise in this.options

Comment: No need to use `$apply()` in the service and `GeolocationService` isn't available in the `config` phase. Remove it as injection in config function

Comment: I did, but it does solve my problem.

Comment: You should be getting error about trying to inject service into config ...no?

Comment: No I don't... But you're right, I should get ... strange

Comment: @user3383709, don't change the question to fit suggestions - it makes the comments meaningless. Leave the question in the original state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ui.router` supports injecting "resolved" values into other to-be-resolved functions. And I'll use @charlietfl good suggestion of resolving `long` and `lat` as a single object:

```
resolve: {
  position: function(GeolocationService){
    return GeolocationService().then(function(position){
      return { long: position.coords.longitude,
               lat:  position.coords.latitude };
    });
  },
  options: function(serviceTest, position){
    return serviceTest.options(position.long, position.lat)
                      .then(function(option){ return option; });
  }
}
```

Comment: I like your approach.... However, using this and then injecting position into my controller still returns "undefined"... sorry, but I do not seem to see what's wrong

Comment: It seems that the config blog is never really accessed. When trying to console.log something from the resolve function it is never be done

Comment: @user3383709, it must be accessed, otherwise you would have received an error trying to inject either `position` or `options`. Make sure you have no obvious errors, and make sure that you have all the necessary `return`s. Also, what is `undefined` - the `position` object or the `long`/`lat` properties?

Comment: 'position' is undefined. Therefore I'll get an error when logging 'long' or 'lat'. All returns are defined...I'll update everything. Just a second

Comment: @user3383709, I think that's because I used `geolocation`, whereas the actual service name is `GeolocationService` - fixed. But anyway, here's a plunker where everything works: http://plnkr.co/edit/3iJcwSvpEkQf2J5Uw5mz?p=preview